# How can I guide FastAPI to pick the right type type from Union

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following models:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class A(BaseModel):
   tag: str
   field1: str

class B(BaseModel):
   tag: str
   field1: str
   field2: str
```

I am using them to define the request body like so:

```
@app.post('/route')
def handle(request: typing.Union[A, B])
```

The [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#union-or-anyof) states:

> include the most specific type first, followed by the less specific type

But I was wondering if there was a way I could guide FastAPI to select the correct model based on the tag. Currently, all of my models have a constant tag (i.e. type `A` always has `tag = 'A'`). Is there a way I can change my model definition to ensure that the assigned model always matches the tag received in the request body?

Currently, I am getting around this by not typing my `handle` function, and instead specifically matching the `tag` to the model, but ideally I would just use `typing.Union` as the type and be confident it is getting it correct.

Comment: try annotating the tag field for A like `tag: Literal['A']` (and similarly for B)

Comment: I checked answer by @rv.kvetch and it works but there is one small downside. You lose request's autogenerated json body field template in OpenAPI.

Comment: @rv.kvetch that worked for me, thank you! Do you want to post it as an answer and I can mark it as so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @rv.kvetch's comment, annotating the `tag` field to be a string literal, e.g. `Literal['A']` meant that correct type was selected every time.

Applying this to the problem above, the code would change to:

```
class A(BaseModel):
   tag: Literal['A']
   field1: str

class B(BaseModel):
   tag: Literal['B']
   field1: str
   field2: str
```

Comment: Where exactly should I put the tag? Can you post the full modified code?

Comment: @DanielLavedoniodeLima, I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: I realise that for this, given that `field1` & `field2` are required: once u try calling that API without putting `field1` & `field2`, the error message will be a union of that for the missing fields in A & B, which doesn't tell the client what was needed, given the tag

Comment: That is true, did you find a way around that @Beast?

Comment: Yes. Refer to class `Item` in `app.py` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337839/11729954). It uses discriminated unions. To access the data and use it normally like any other Pydantic type, access the `__root__` attribute of `Item.__root__`