# How to generate Pydantic model for multiple different objects

Tags: python, validation, nested, fastapi, pydantic

I need to have a variable `covars` that contains an unknown number of entries, where each entry is one of three different custom `Pydantic` models. In this case, each entry describes a variable for my application.

Specifically, I want `covars` to have the following form. It is shown here for three entries, namely `variable1`, `variable2` and `variable3`, representing the three different types of entries. Though, when deployed, the application must allow to receive more than three entries, and not all entry types need to be present in a request.

```py
covars = {
            'variable1':  # type: integer
                {
                    'guess': 1,
                    'min': 0,
                    'max': 2,
                },
            'variable2':  # type: continuous
                {
                    'guess': 12.2,
                    'min': -3.4,
                    'max': 30.8,
                },
            'variable3':  # type: categorical
                {
                    'guess': 'red',
                    'options': {'red', 'blue', 'green'},
                }
        }
```

I have successfully created the three different entry types as three separate `Pydantic` models

```py
import pydantic
from typing import Set, Dict, Union


class IntVariable(pydantic.BaseModel):
    guess: int
    min: int
    max: int


class ContVariable(pydantic.BaseModel):
    guess: float
    min: float
    max: float


class CatVariable(pydantic.BaseModel):
    guess: str
    options: Set[str] = {}
```

Notice the data type difference between `IntVariable` and `ContVariable`.

**My question:** How to make a `Pydantic` model that allows combining any number of entries of types `IntVariable`, `ContVariable` and `CatVariable` to get the output I am looking for?

The plan is to use this model to verify the data as it is being posted to the API, and then store a serialized version to the application db (using `ormar`).

Answer (score 8):

First, since you don't seem to be using pre-defined keys, you could use a [custom root type](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types), which allows you to have arbitrary key names in a pydantic model, as discussed [here](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1802). Next, you could use a [`Union`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions), which allows a model attribute to accept different types (and also ignores the order when defined). Thus, you can pass a number of entries of your three models, regardless of the order.

Since `IntVariable` and `ContVariable` models have exactly the same number of attributes and key names, when passing `float` numbers to `min` and `max`, they are converted to `int`, as there is no way for pydantic to differentiate between the two models. On top of that, `min` and `max` are reserved keywords in Python; thus, it would be preferable to change them, as shown below.

```
from typing import Dict, Set, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class IntVariable(BaseModel):
    guess: int
    i_min: int
    i_max: int

class ContVariable(BaseModel):
    guess: float
    f_min: float
    f_max: float


class CatVariable(BaseModel):
    guess: str
    options: Set[str]
    
class Item(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union [IntVariable, ContVariable, CatVariable]

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(covars: Dict[str, Item]):
    return covars
```

Input sample is shown below. Make sure to use square brackets `[]` when typing the `options` `Set`, as FastAPI would otherwise complain, if braces `{}` were used.

```json
{
   "variable1":{
      "guess":1,
      "i_min":0,
      "i_max":2
   },
   "variable2":{
      "guess":"orange",
      "options":["orange", "yellow", "brown"]
   },
   "variable3":{
      "guess":12.2,
      "f_min":-3.4,
      "f_max":30.8
   },
   "variable4":{
      "guess":"red",
      "options":["red", "blue", "green"]
   },
   "variable5":{
      "guess":2.15,
      "f_min":-1.75,
      "f_max":11.8
   }
}
```

### Update

Since with the above, when a `ValidationError` is raised for one of the models, errors for all three models are raised (instead of raising errors only for that specific model), one could use [Discriminated Unions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804). With Discriminated Unions, *"only one explicit error is raised in case of failure"*. Example below:

**app.py**

```python
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Dict, Set, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Literal

app = FastAPI()

class IntVariable(BaseModel):
    model_type: Literal['int']
    guess: int
    i_min: int
    i_max: int

class ContVariable(BaseModel):
    model_type: Literal['cont']
    guess: float
    f_min: float
    f_max: float


class CatVariable(BaseModel):
    model_type: Literal['cat']
    guess: str
    options: Set[str]
    
class Item(BaseModel):
    __root__: Union[IntVariable, ContVariable, CatVariable] = Field(..., discriminator='model_type')

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(covars: Dict[str, Item]):
    return covars
```

**Test data**

```json
{
   "variable1":{
      "model_type": "int",
      "guess":1,
      "i_min":0,
      "i_max":2
   },
   "variable2":{
      "model_type": "cat",
      "guess":"orange",
      "options":["orange", "yellow", "brown"]
   },
   "variable3":{
      "model_type": "cont",
      "guess":12.2,
      "f_min":-3.4,
      "f_max":30.8
   },
   "variable4":{
      "model_type": "cat",
      "guess":"red",
      "options":["red", "blue", "green"]
   },
   "variable5":{
      "model_type": "cont",
      "guess":2.15,
      "f_min":-1.75,
      "f_max":11.8
   }
}
```

An alternative solution would be to have a [dependency](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) function, where you iterate over the dictionary and try parsing each item/entry in the dictionary using the three models within a `try-catch` block, similar to what described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71228281/17865804). However, that would require either looping through all the models, or having a discriminator in the entry (such as `"model_type"` above), indicating which model you should try parsing.

Comment: thanks @chris! Very helpful. However I ended up using another solution, which I posted below

Comment: In newer versions it will be `Item(RootModel)` and field name `root` instead of `__root__`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the problem using custom validators. Adding it here to complement the solution by @Chris.

I used a couple of other features to make this work. First, I set up the three types as `Enum` to constrain the options. Secondly, I used `StrictInt`, `StrictFloat` and `StrictStr` to circumvent the challenge that `python` will convert an `int` to a `float` if the first option presented in e.g. `guess` is `float`, i.e. if I were to use `guess: Union[float,int,str]`. Thirdly, I remove the input `vtype` (which is of type `VarType`) and replace it with another field `type` of type `str` using custom replacement via a `root_validator`.

```
import ormar
import pydantic
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import Json, validator, root_validator, StrictInt, StrictFloat, StrictStr
from typing import Set, Dict, Union, Optional
import uuid


class VarType(Enum):
    int = "int"
    cont = "cont"
    cat = "cat"


class Variable(pydantic.BaseModel):
    vtype: VarType
    guess: Union[StrictFloat, StrictInt, StrictStr]
    min: Optional[Union[StrictFloat, StrictInt]] = None
    max: Optional[Union[StrictFloat, StrictInt]] = None
    options: Optional[Set[str]] = None

    # this check is needed to make 'type' available for 'check_guess' validator, but it is not otherwise needed since
    # VarType itself ensures type validation
    @validator('vtype', allow_reuse=True)
    def req_check(cls, t):
        assert t.value in ['int', 'cont', 'cat'], "'vtype' must take value from set ['int', 'cont', 'cat']"
        return t

    # add new field called "type"
    @root_validator(pre=False, allow_reuse=True)
    def insert_type(cls, values):
        if values['vtype'].value == 'int':
            values['type'] = 'int'
        elif values['vtype'].value == 'cont':
            values['type'] = 'float'
        elif values['vtype'].value == 'cat':
            values['type'] = 'str'
        return values

    @root_validator(pre=True, allow_reuse=True)
    def set_guessminmax_types(cls, values):
        if values['vtype'] == 'int':
            values['guess'] = int(values['guess'])
            values['min'] = int(values['min'])
            values['max'] = int(values['max'])
        elif values['vtype'] == 'cont':
            values['guess'] = float(values['guess'])
            values['min'] = float(values['min'])
            values['max'] = float(values['max'])
        return values


    # check right data type of 'guess'
    @validator('guess', allow_reuse=True)
    def check_guess_datatype(cls, g, values):
        if values['vtype'].value == 'int':
            assert isinstance(g, int), "data type mismatch between 'guess' and 'vtype'. Expected type 'int' from 'guess' but received " + str(
                type(g))
            return g
        elif values['vtype'].value == 'cont':
            assert isinstance(g, float), "data type mismatch between 'guess' and 'vtype'. Expected type 'float' from 'guess' but received " + str(
                type(g))
            return g
        elif values['vtype'].value == 'cat':
            assert isinstance(g, str), "data type mismatch between 'guess' and 'vtype'. Expected type 'str' from 'guess' but received " + str(
                type(g))
            return g

    # check that 'min' is included for types 'int', 'cont'
    @validator('min', allow_reuse=True)
    def check_min_included(cls, m, values):
        if values['vtype'].value in ['int', 'cont']:
            assert m is not None
            return m

    # check that 'max' is included for types 'int', 'cont'
    @validator('max', allow_reuse=True)
    def check_max_included(cls, m, values):
        if values['vtype'].value in ['int', 'cont']:
            assert m is not None
            return m

    # check that 'options' is included for type 'cat'
    @validator('options', allow_reuse=True)
    def check_options_included(cls, op, values):
        if values['vtype'].value == 'cat':
            assert op is not None
            return op

    # removes all fields which have value None
    @root_validator(pre=False, allow_reuse=True)
    def remove_all_nones(cls, values):
        values = {k: v for k, v in values.items() if v is not None}
        return values

    class Config:
        fields = {"vtype": {"exclude": True}}
```