# How to use more than one BaseModel in request payload which are separate(Basemodels) in python FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

Iam trying using :

```
async def method_name(info:Union[GenericDataObjectSchema,TransactionSpecificDataObjectSchema]):
```

but in basemodel I am getting only the values of GenericDataObjectSchema Basemodel if I want both the basemodel values what can be the solution?

Iam expecting 2 basemodels values to be populated in the request body but Iam getting only the values of one basemodel.

example Basemodel:

```
class TransactionDataSchema(BaseModel):
    x : str  
    y : str
    
    
    
class TransactionSpecificDataObjectSchema(BaseModel):
    m : str
    n : str
    o: str
    
    
class GenericDataObjectSchema(BaseModel):
    a : str 
    b : str
    c : str
    d : str
    e : str
    f : str
    g : TransactionDataSchema
    h : str
    i : str
```

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337839/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804) helpful.

Comment: `Union` in typing means that it can be _either_ of the types, not that the objects are merged into a single object for you: "Union type; Union[X, Y] is equivalent to X | Y and means either X or Y." [library/typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) - if you want merge them, create a new class that inherits from both classes `class MergedSchema(GenericDataObjectSchema, TransactionSpecificDataObjectSchema)`