# How to merge models to one BaseClass, but is still distinguishable

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I have several models:

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel


class Dog(SQLModel, table=true):
    __tablename__ = "dog"
    name : str
    size: int
    color: str

class Cat(SQLModel, table=true):
    __tablename__ = "cat"
    name: str
    size: int
    color: str
```

and then I have a pandatic schema:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

 class Cat(BaseModel):
     name: str
     size: int
     color: str

class Dog(BaseModel):
    name: str
    size: int
    color: str


class Pets(BaseModel):
    name: str
    size: int
    color: str
```

and now I have a FastAPI function:

```
 from app.models import Cat, Dog
 from app.schemas import Pets

@router.get("/pets", response_model=List[Pets])
async def get_pets(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):

    pets = []
    
    query = select(Cat)
    cats = (await session.execute(query)).scalars().fetchall()

    query = select(Dog)
    dogs = (await session.execute(query)).scalars().fetchall()

    pets.extend(dogs, cats)
    return pets
```

This is the result:

```
 [{'color': 'blue', 'name': 'bob', 'size': 5},
  {'color': 'green', 'name': 'tiger', 'size': 5},
  {'color': 'purple', 'name': 'rob', 'size': 2}]
```

How could I distinguish which model the entry is from? I could add an attribute to each model, but this doesn't seem very smart and waste space.

`Update`:

I tried this:

```
from typing import Annotated, Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Cat(BaseModel):
    model_type = Literal["cat"]
    name: str
    size: int
    color: str

Pets = Annotated[Union[Cat, Dog], Field(discriminator='model_type')]
```

But do I understand it correct, that I still need the attribute also at the SQLModel? But then I have in each database row the string "cat" or "dog".

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337839/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71228281/17865804) as well

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for the comments. They are very helpful! But do I still need the attribute model_type als at the table?