# Using Pydantic with Fields Having Multiple Valid Types and Custom Validation Classes

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, pydantic

#### Problem Description

I'm working on a Pydantic model, where I have a field that needs to accept multiple types of values (e.g., car model and bike model) and validate them through custom validation classes.

#### Pydantic Model

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: ???  # How do I define this field to accept car and bike models and apply custom validation?


from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Union

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field: Union[CarModel, BikeModel]  # How to use custom validators here?
```

I would like to know how to define the `my_field` in my Pydantic model to accept both `car` and `bike` models as valid input types and apply the respective custom validation classes.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71337839/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71228281/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Annotated, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from pydantic.functional_validators import AfterValidator


# custom validator for CarModel
def is_four_wheels(num: int) -> int:
    assert num == 4, f"{num} is not valid"
    return num


# custom validator for BikeModel
def is_two_wheels(num: int) -> int:
    assert num == 2, f"{num} is not valid"
    return True


class CarModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    category: str = "car"
    wheels: Annotated[int, AfterValidator(is_four_wheels)]


class BikeModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    category: str = "bike"
    wheels: Annotated[int, AfterValidator(is_two_wheels)]


class VehicleModel(BaseModel):
    type: Union[CarModel, BikeModel]


car = CarModel(name="Toyota", wheels=4)

bike = BikeModel(name="Suzuki", wheels=2)


try:
    vehicle = VehicleModel(type=car)
    print(vehicle.model_dump_json())

except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

'AfterValidator' applies the custom validators after pydantic's inner validation logic. You can learn more about how it works [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.AfterValidator)